# WPF Databinding to Window

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I want to link the DataBinding of a listbox item with a new window

A "Name" button should open a new window with the DataBinding of the listbox item.

The Binding is a .xml File:

```xml
<People>
   <Person image="Test.jpg" company="" position="" website="" chat="" notes="">
      <Name first_name="Max" second_name="" last_name="Mustermann" salutation="" />
      <Email email1="" email2="" email3="" />
      <Phone_Numbers business="" private="" mobile="" />
      <Business_Adress street="" place="" state="" postalcode="" country="" />
      <Private_Adress street="" place="" state="" postalcode="" country="" />
   </Person>
</People>
```

And the new Window should be linked to the Name Element of the Person.

Though there will be more then one person, but the window should be linked to the right person.

This is the XmlDataProvider:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Name="XmlData" Source="People.xml" XPath="/People/Person" />
```

And the binding of the listbox looks like this:

```xml
<ListBox 
   Grid.Row="0" 
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" 
   x:Name="PeopleListBox" 
   SelectionMode="Single">
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
               <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1} {2}">
                  <Binding XPath="Name/@last_name" />
                  <Binding XPath="Name/@first_name" />
                  <Binding XPath="Name/@second_name" />
               </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How I can do this, because it opens only the first Person

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: I have added some code

Answer (score 0):

Unless `DataContext` is set to `XmlData` your `ItemsSource` binding won't work. You did not mention where you define `XmlDataProvider` because if in `Resources` then you need to specify `x:Key` instead of `x:Name` and then you would have to specify it as `Binding.Source`. You also did not say what is `People.xml` as it must be added to your solution as a resource

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData" XPath="/People/Person" Source="People.xml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlData}}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1} {2}">
                            <Binding XPath="Name/@last_name" />
                            <Binding XPath="Name/@first_name" />
                            <Binding XPath="Name/@second_name" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

or you can load it manually by setting `XmlDataProvider.Source` manually in code